# What annotations and configuration I should make to parse JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a request(POST or GET), having one variable "data" (coming from Xcode)
now data have assigned JSON object

```
data={"method":"Auth","action":"login"}
```

now I have a bean having exactly these two fields(i.e. method,action)

now in Spring controller I have method "login".

I want this method to be invoked based on value in "action" of the request JSON object.

Now, I'm not getting what exactly types of annotation i should use.

Please help..

Comment: What's Xcode? The Apple IDE? How does that fit in with Spring / JSON?

Comment: actually that Iphone APP sends request to Spring and the common format for communication is JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to the classpath, and [add `<mvc:annotation-driven>` to your Spring context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven), then Spring will automatically [register a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` for JSON Objects](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-mapping-json-converter).

Now Annotate your method like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/some/path")
public YourResponseObject someName(@RequestBody YourRequestObject data){
    // do something here
}
```

(Both `YourRequestObject` and `YourResponseObject` will be automatically converted to and from JSON, but this works only for POST requests AFAIK)

Comment: I did what you have said...but now error coming like this "Can not deserialize instance of com.slktechlabs.datasource.RequestBean out of START_ARRAY token"

Comment: @Ravi please add the stack trace to your question, also: what does the JSON String (exactly) look like?

Comment: I did what you have said...but now error coming like this "Can not deserialize instance of com.slktechlabs.datasource.RequestBean out of START_ARRAY token"

Comment: @Ravi please add the stack trace to your question, also: what does the JSON String (exactly) look like? (we can keep playing this game a while, you know :-))

Comment: the discovery found that it's coming in the format [Object object] so I changed type to String and then made JSON from String..but your first answer was worth